# Where do I starting to find the memory leak after porting from i386 to x86_64?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, compilation, x86-64

I successfully compiled and run [Borealis](http://cs.brown.edu/research/borealis/public/) under Fedora core 12 i386 Pentium dual core and g++ 4.1.1, Now I hope it can run under FC20 x86_64 i7 dual core. After modifying some codes(**I think these modifications are nothing with its performation**) and installing several additional packages Borealis needs, I successfully compiled Borealis under FC20 x86_64 and it was able to run. But when running, I found that there was **severe memory leakage** , gnome-system-monitor displayed using memory changed from 1.8G to 5G after it run 5 seconds. Under FC3 i386, the memory holds 200M during running.

I do not know how to start finding this cause, any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Run it under `valgrind --leak-check=full`.

Comment: @timrau, I have run it using `valgrind --leak-check=full`, there are many `X(such as 1 or 4,294,967,264) bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1,296 of 1,296`, but I do not know why Boreais is ok under FC3

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue at this point. Yes, you have  potential memory leaks (it would certainly appear so), but you also have the valgrind report. So.. what is stopping you from investigating and fixing the reported findings? This issue this question seems to be postulating isn't fixing the leaks, but *why* there are leaks. To that the only reasonable answer (outside of incorrect usage by the *client*) is because the author (potentially unknowingly) made assumptions for a 32bit platform rather than platform independence.

Comment: @WhozCraig,you are right, This project was started since 2002. All its manual was for 32bit platform.

Comment: I had a feeling from the link you provided. I thought I saw it was no longer under active management since 2008. Were I you I'd investigate if they have a x64-compliant alternative toolkit that you can port your client-code to, as it may well be overkill to port-up a library that is already deprecated. Best of luck, though.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I do not hope to get any supporting because the project is closed, I want to do it myself. There will be many questions I can not resolve except giving up?

Comment: @abelard20008 If that is the case, I'd spend some time investigating the common pitfalls of code poorly written to be bit-depth platform-independent before embarking on fixing their lib for x64 compliance. It will accomplish two things: (1) give you some ideas on what to look for that can be causing the issues you're seeing, and (b) it will *significantly* improve the way you code *your own code* both in and out of this effort (thats the real win, btw).